# UIDesign Advice

Tags: user-interface, ipad, uitableview, scroll

I want to achiece the following scenario,

[image]

My idea is to have three different tableview. But i have stuck up with the scrolling problem that if i scroll tableview3 vertically, tableview1 & tableview2 should also scroll.

Is there any other idea for implementing this? Or else a solution for my scrolling problem?

**Note:** The number of columns are dynamic.

**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently in the process of implementing a similar UI system, I gave up on using UITableView for it in order to make things a little more 'dynamic'. Re-implemnting all of UITableView from scratch is a really fun exercise!

If UITableView will still work for you, all you need to remember is tableview's are subclasses of UIScrollView, which has delegate methods for scrolling. Use those, along with setContentOffset and you can trivially sync the scrolling of multiple tables.

Comment: will the setContentOffset looks like the natural scrolling?

Comment: If you wrap it in an animation block it should

Comment: How are you handling the horizontal scrolling of the middle panel btw?

Comment: The grey portion is achieved by placing the tableview over the scrollview.